# Is there any build in Dependency injection container in .NET framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

As vNext has arrived we have a build in DI container that we can use as we need. But I also heard that earlier .NET frameworks also partially supports DI (not telling about Unity or any other container). For example, creation of a controller or a view in run time (I do not have wide knowledge about it). So I wanted to know is there any DI container already exist in earlier .NET frameworks, if there is any can we use them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built in DI container in previous versions of ASP.NET. You can pretty easily setup and use the 3rd party ones (`Ninject`, `Autofac`, `Castle Windsor`, `Unity`, etc). They are all available on Nuget and can easily be added to an MVC project. There's a pretty good tutorial here for Unity: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

As for vNext, the ASP.NET team has different populators for common DI containers. You can review my overview of the built in one here: http://davidzych.com/2014/06/02/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext/, and also my overview of setting up Castle Windsor in vNext here: http://davidzych.com/2014/07/28/asp-net-vnext-dependency-injection-with-castle-windsor/